# Pass a node command to cmd using javascript

Tags: javascript, cmd

On clicking a button, I want to run a node file `main.js` on cmd terminal.

I did:

```
var ip ="f:\ node main.js ";

function pingItjs(ip) {
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell"); 
    oShell.run("cmd.exe /k" + ip); 
}
```

but it only opens a cmd with `F:\` drive and doesn't append the command:

```
node main.js
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) library that does exactly that :) called `node-cmd`. But you have to use this inside `NodeJS`.

With pure JS (without NodeJS), I'd do something like this:

```
// Instantiate the Shell object and invoke its execute method.
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

var commandtoRun = "f:\ node main.js ";

// Invoke the execute method.  
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, "", "", "open", "1");
```